# What's the story behind the GEM-63 delay?

Tags: srb, atlas-v

The Wikipedia page on the [GEM-63](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite-Epoxy_Motor#GEM-63) says that the Atlas V will start using it "in July 2019." But the [Atlas V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_V) page says that the switch from the AJ-60A will happen "in the near future." That the switch hasn't happened yet is [confirmed by ULA](https://www.ulalaunch.com/about/news/2020/03/27/united-launch-alliance-successfully-launches-first-national-security-space-mission-for-the-u.s.-space-force): Apparently yesterday's launch used AJ-90A boosters.

Okay, fine. So I Googled "GEM-63" and "GEM-63 delay". The only result that looked relevant was a [Spaceflight Now article](https://spaceflightnow.com/2019/10/20/solid-rocket-motor-test-fired-for-atlas-5-debut-next-year) from October about a test fire. It says the plan for the first launch was September 2020. It didn't say anything about the reason for the delay.

Does anyone know why the booster switch was delayed? Was it a Northrop Grumman issue? A ULA issue? Maybe ULA wants the NROL-101 spy satellite launch to be the first use of the new boosters, and the satellite was delayed?

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  Nice first question.

Comment: https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2020/nasa-s-laser-communications-relay-demonstration-mission-leaves-goddard-space-flight-center

Comment: http://www.parabolicarc.com/2018/05/16/gao-assessment-laser-communications-relay-demonstration/ perhaps NASA cuts caused delays to part of the payload

Comment: @JCRM Okay, so if I understand correctly the LCRD mission that you linked is part of the STP-3 payload. As of September 2018 STP-3 was apparently planned to be the first mission that used the GEM-63, but the Spaceflight Now article I linked says that the NROL-101 mission is now planned to be the first use of the booster, this September. Nextspaceflight.com has the STP-3 mission down for NET October, which is consistent with the STP-3 mission slipping so far that it's not expected to be the first GEM-63 launch.

Comment: Do you suppose that individual launch contracts specify things like whether ULA is allowed to use the GEM-63 for the first time? It's supposed to be a drop-in replacement for the old booster, but at least early on the risk is of course still higher. Customer reluctance to be a guinea pig could explain the delay, though it's weird that the NRO would be more willing than others — I was under the impression that spy sats were more expensive than most payloads. You'd think it would make more sense to take the risk on a military comsat or something.